# Incrementing gitversion version

Tags: gitversion

I am using GitVersion for versioning. I notice I get versions like this:
#0.1.0+12

However, versions like this don't get picked up by dotnet pack or ProGet (they cut out everything from + onwards). At the moment, I am developing on master (Which I will protect and change later), but am hoping the last 0 increments per commit, like 0.1.1, 0.1.2, etc. My yml file is:

```
mode: Mainline
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
increment: Patch
```